# touchesBegan - iPhone app UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, touchesbegan

I have a `touchesBegan:` method which works fine. However I recently added a UIView (a button) to my UIViewController and now the button isn't registering taps, however my `touchesBegan:` method is.

How can I tell my `touchesBegan:` method to avoid the button?

Here is my current `touchesBegan:` method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
    NSLog(@"touches began");
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    switch ([touch tapCount]) 
    {
        case 1:
            break;

        case 2:
            if(something)
                [doing something];

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: As always, double-check to make sure you've properly connected the button in IB if you created it in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the button is in front (`[self.view bringSubviewToFront: myButton]`). Then you can ask the touch in which in view it occurred:

```
if ([touch.view isEqualTo: myButton]) {
    NSLog(@"touch was on button");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  When I moved my button to the front (in code via UIViewController.bringSubviewToFront) the touchesBegan no longer was fired when I clicked on the button.  I'm running Xcode 4.2, in the simulator.